# Delete the rows that contain the string - Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert columns in DataFrame from OBJECT to INT. I need to completely delete the lines that contain the string.

The following expression "saves" the data I care about and converts the column from the OBJECT to INT type:

```
df["column name"] = df["column name"].astype(str).str.replace(r'/\d+$', '').astype(int)
```

However,before this, rows that contain letters (A-Z) I want to delete completely.

I tried:

```
df[~df["column name"].str.lower().str.startswith('A-Z')]
```

Also I tried a few other expressions, however, no data cleans.

DataFrame looks something like this:

```
          A         B         C
0       8161       0454   9600
1 -     3780       1773   1450
2       2564       0548   5060
3       1332       9179   2040
4       6010       3263   1050
5   I Forgot       7849   1400/10000
```

Col C - 1400/10000 - The first expression I wrote simply removes "/ 10000" and remains "1400"

Now I need to remove the word expressions as in the "A5"

Comment: would you care to share a sample from your data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expression you can create a mask for all rows that contains a character between [a-z]. Then you can drop this rows. Like this:

```
mask = df['a'].str.lower().str.contains("[a-z]")
idx = df.index[mask]
df = df.drop(idx, axis=0)
```